# Heroku crashes Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Heroku bamboo-mri-1.9.2 with Amazon RDS database.

My app do crash on Heroku but not on my local pc.

My PC:
Ruby 1.9.2p136
Rails 3.0.3

My Heroku log http://pastie.org/1690168

My heroku as 1 dyno and 0 workers

Comment: You are asking a LOT of questions on here. too many. This isn't a support department. Your problem lies on line 32 of your pastie. You should ask Heroku for support first.

Comment: I agree I have asked a lot of questions. I would say to many.  Now my Heroku server works! Just 1 last question my stylesheet aren't loading I am using <%= stylesheet_link_tag "Public" %> in my layout files. I can visit my stylesheet on http://myaapp.heroku.com/stylesheets/public.css

Comment: My problem was that it should not be a large P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is because Heroku has not installed the dynamic form plugin/gem.

See this article
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-cli-plugins

Comment: Did forget to add gem 'dynamic form' to my gem file